# How to print Javascript order of code execution by line numbers [No Debugging]

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, npm

In my Node.JS code, i wanted to know some of my asynchronous code execution without debugging (debugging could interrupt my asynchronous cals) application by printing out all `filename: line numbers`, in order of code execution.

As of now,  i'm using `DEBUG=* npm start` to see debug logs on express. But, it's not giving enough information i'm looking for.

Is there any better way or module to achieve this?

Comment: Have you checked out [`console.trace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace)? As an alternative you could use breakpoints.

Comment: @JasonCust, i'm trying to enhance existing code which is not by me and i'm not getting errors. Without injecting so much code i wanted to print file and line numbers of each line of code in same order of execution. Can i achieve that using console.trace?